# Issue with nuget config transformation files

Tags: nuget, config-transformation

I am creating a nuget package that besides other files contains also configuration files such as: f1.config, f2.config etc. These configuration files are in turn referenced in the web.config file.

As these configuration files may or may not exist in the project where this package would be installed, I have renamed them to f1.config.transform, f2.config.transform.

While the installation of the package runs flawlessly in all possible scenarios, uninstalling is not working as expected in one particular case. Namely, if let say the config file f2.config did not exist in the project before the installation, it will not be removed when uninstalling the package.

Any ideas?

EDIT: NuGet spec file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>WCFServicesProxyPackage</id>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <title />
        <authors>Shkelzen a. Saraqini</authors>
        <owners>Shkelzen a. Saraqini</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>WCF services proxy package.</description>
        <language>en-CA</language>
        <references>
            <reference file="WCFServices.Proxy.dll" />
        </references>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.Local.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.Local.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.Production.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.Production.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.QA.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.behaviors.QA.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.Local.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.Local.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.Production.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.Production.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.QA.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.bindings.QA.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.Local.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.Local.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.Production.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.Production.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.QA.config.transform" target="content\config\system.serviceModel.client.QA.config.transform" />
        <file src="content\Web.config.transform" target="content\Web.config.transform" />
        <file src="lib\net40\WCFServices.Proxy.dll" target="lib\net40\WCFServices.Proxy.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you install/uninstall the config files? Could you share some PowerShell snippets from your scripts (assuming you're using PowerShell install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 scripts in your package)?

Maybe you can force the removal of the files: http://www.timvw.be/2011/10/18/force-the-removal-of-a-file-with-powershell/

Also, it is likely this functionality will be improved in the future, if and when XDT becomes OSS for NuGet to benefit from it.

Comment: The config files get installed as the part of the NuGet package installation. I edited the question to include the NuGet spec file. I am not using the install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 at all.

Comment: Did you find anything in the logs (Visual Studio Output window) during uninstall? During uninstall, NuGet skips files that have been modified since installation.

Comment: Two messages only: Successfully removed 'WCFServicesProxyPackage 1.0.3' from TestMvcApp and Successfully uninstalled 'WCFServicesProxyPackage 1.0.3'.

The *.config files that did not exist prior to the package installation remain in the project, while the content of those that existed is reverted back to the content before the installation. I hope the description makes sense. Thanks Xavier.

Comment: If no adjustments are made to the *.config files, then the expected behavior is to have the content reverted to the original files that existed, and the files removed that did not exist. The latter seems to be an issue. Could you file a bug on http://nuget.codeplex.com with steps to reproduce (preferably attach a sample package)?

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I'll file a bug soon.

Comment: This is a limitiation of the xml tranformations, see:  http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/437548 and http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3145.